# Bulk import and redirect 301 (over 14K url) in core_url_rewrite or on server

Tags: url-rewrite, 301-redirect

I have to redirect over 14K urls from another system to magento core_url_rewrite. What is the preferred method, to place these urls in database, or to redirect the ursl from .htaccess file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

htaccess is good Idea .But it is **too tuff write code** for  **14k urls  in a htaccess file**,

Better **idea to rewrite using magento code** and that case ,you can use 3rd party extensions like

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/optimise-web-s-mass-301-redirects-for-404-pages.html

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smooth-move-seo-301-redirect-handler.html

**Optimise Web's Mass 301 Redirects for 404 Pages**  is best as per as my thought

Comment: Thx, i used this link - https://www.byte.nl/blog/create-bulk-301-redirects-in-magento, and everything seems working ..